# Eclipse projects no longer exporting runnable jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, raspberry-pi

Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0) on Windows 10 Pro (20H2)
Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian 10
Java 11 (since it is the latest I've seen on the Raspberry Pi.

I've recently encountered a problem while exporting runnable jar files. On new and older programs in the workspace, when they are exported as runnable jar files on the Windows 10 Pro and moved to the Raspberry Pi, I get the message "Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file test.jar"

Having written a "Hello World" program and exported it, it ran just fine. This leads me to believe it is something with the project name, the Maven repositories, some quirk on the Raspberry Pi, or some other unknown.

The project names are now "ButtonMediaPlayerV24" where 24 indicates 2.4 (to keep previous versions, the period was removed in hopes it would fix the issue)

The Maven Repositories are VLCj and pi4j.

Have anything I should check or try?

Tried:
creating a new project, with the name "ButtonMediaPlayer" with the same result.

UPDATE 1:
After gutting the program and putting it into the test project, I found GPIO 30 and 31 had "PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN" in the initiation, which was given as an error message after getting rid of the additional classes.

UPDATE 2:
The Maven repositories are not the problem, and the project name isn't an issue.

Further updates if I find more.

Comment: A JAR fild is actually a zip file. Can you open it as such, show the MANIFEST.MF and check if the main class is present and correct?

Comment: Please don't add things like 'SOLVED' to the question title or question body. Instead post the solution as an answer (which you already did), and accept your answer after the timeout. Accepting an answer is what marks a question as 'solved'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be the way I was trying to create local version control, which involved using Windows Explorer to create a new copy, and rename it. It seems to be possible to do this, but Eclipse must rename the file to update not obvious locations where the file name is. Without that, it seems to break every time.